# before_create undefined method `has_role?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise with relation `user has_many websites`
when creating a new website raises `undefined method has_role? for nil:NilClass`

```
class Website  < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :priority

  belongs_to :user
  before_create :set_priority

 private 
  def set_priority
    if user.has_role? :admin
      self.priority = 3
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: because the `user` is nil. Just because a website belongs to a user, doesn't mean it always has one.

Comment: @sevenseacat Could you advise me how can i check the user role in callback?

Comment: the user doesn't have one, because they don't exist.

Comment: `if user && user.has_role? :admin`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on sevenseacat's comment, should all of your websites be required to belong to a user? If you are always expecting that the website has a user then you should validate the field:

```
validates :user_id, presence: true # Enforce the presence of a user for each website
```

You can also make your method error proof by checking that the user object exists before trying to use it:

```
def set_priority
  if user && user.has_role? :admin
    self.priority = 3
  end
end
```

Be aware that if there is no user object this will leave `priority` unchanged - do you need to set a different priority for non admins or if user is blank?